# How to use shell command in GNU Make to echo string

Tags: shell, command-line, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have the following lines in my makefile:

```
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    @echo "Running Clean"
    $(shell if [ -e exe ]; then rm exe; else echo "no files"; fi)
```

When I run:

```
make clean
```

I get the following output on the shell

```
Running Clean
no files
make: no: Command not found
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 127
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of `$(shell ...)`.   What you want is:

```
.PHONY : clean
clean:
    @echo "Running Clean"
    @if [ -e exe ]; then rm exe; else echo "no files"; fi
```

As far as an explanation of what's going wrong -- when you first run the clean target, make will expand all make variables and functions in the recipes before it starts running them -- because `$(shell ...)` only has one `$`, this is considered a make function.   Make runs the command, which outputs `no files` to stdout, and replaces the call with that string, and then starts executing the recipes...   So now make sees the following:

```
clean:
    @echo "Running Clean"
    no files
```

When it tries to run `no files`, due to the lack of a `@`, it echos the line to the screen, and then passes the command to the shell.  Because the shell doesn't recognize the keyword `no` it outputs the error you're seeing.   Make itself then fails because the shell returned an error.

Comment: Yes, this worked! I tried to up vote you but I need 15 reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Hey all I'm the same guy who asked this question but I found an answer right after I posted this, I think I'll leave this up (unless this is against stackoverflow etiquette) in case someone else has the same problems. My solution was echoing the string to stdout.

```
$(shell if [ -e exe ]; then rm exe; else echo "no files" >&2; fi)
```